# How to store old state and new state in a boolean when simulating state changing in Game of Life?

Tags: algorithm, bit, conways-game-of-life

This question is about the LeetCode's problem [Game of Life](https://leetcode.com/problems/game-of-life/).
In Game of Life, I can save the old state of cell in the last bit of int, and new in the second last. And then solve it in-place.
But If the cell map is a **boolean matrix**, how to solve it in-place. I mean, if there a way to store old and new state in a boolean in this game?

Comment: You can't do it in place.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? A Bool is not a Bit, but at least a byte so you can as well create a char-array and use the Bit-trick. If you really care for space, then http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/ is the place to go.

Comment: I just want to find out the algorithm to solve this problem. It can use Bit-trick but if the cell is just one bit is there any way to solve?

Comment: @FooBar "at least a byte" Do Turing machines have bytes? What about lambda calculus?

Comment: No. Turing machines don't use the concept of a byte. But why is that important here?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot solve it in place with a Boolean matrix.  A Boolean has only 2 states; your required information is 4 states (live-live, live-dead, dead-live, dead-dead).

Yes, depending on the implementation, you might be able to declare a boolean cell and get *more* than just two states ... but that violates the abstract concept of *Boolean*.